# I am creating a new page in ionic 5 but it is giving this error **Could not find an NgModule**

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

When i run `ionic g page pages/first`

Complete error line: `Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule. [ERROR] Could not generate page`

And When I run `ionic g page src/app/pages/first`

it get the new folder in the main of the folder, not in the subfolders src/app like before

I tried to downgrade ionic cli but still the same error, today i received an update of npm and I also updated ionic cli but error is not resolved yet.

My Ionic CLI version is **6.11.1**

Comment: ionic released v6 ? lol I think you meant angular v 6.11

Comment: no no its ionic cli version 6.11.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue after 2 days

Update to the latest version of **@ionic/angular-toolkit**

Run the following command

`npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.3.3 --save-dev`